# Can't get data in specific format using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to work with a messy sheet. In order to do so, i've used pandas to get extract data and put it into a dataframe. I have two problems: the first one is the date, which is coming as an object and exporting as "[Timestamp('1977-01-26 00:00:00')]" into the excel file. The second one is the square brackets, which goes within the data.

Here is how i get data:

```
linha = 0

while 1>0:
    
    if pd.isna(dataframe.iloc[linha,1])==False: 
        cod_turma = dataframe.iloc[[linha],[0]].values[0]
        cod_curso = dataframe.iloc[[linha],[1]].values[0]
        linha = linha + 1
        
    else:
        matricula = dataframe.iloc[[linha],[0]].values[0]
        nome = dataframe.iloc[[linha],[2]].values[0]
        data = dataframe.iloc[[linha+1],[0]].values[0]
        telefone = dataframe.iloc[[linha+1],[2]].values[0]
        cep = dataframe.iloc[[linha+1],[6]].values[0]
        cidade = dataframe.iloc[[linha+2],[4]].values[0]
        estado = dataframe.iloc[[linha+2],[8]].values[0]
        situacaomatricula = dataframe.iloc[[linha+2],[0]].values[0]
        email = dataframe.iloc[[linha+3],[0]].values[0]
        #aluno = Aluno(cod_turma, cod_curso, matricula, nome, data, telefone, cep, cidade, estado, situacaomatricula, email)
        #aluno = [cod_turma, cod_curso, matricula, nome, data, telefone, cep, cidade, estado, situacaomatricula, email]
        #lista_alunos.append(aluno)
        df = df.append({'Cod_turma': cod_turma, 'Cod_curso': cod_curso, 'Matricula': matricula, 'Nome': nome, 'Data': data, 'Telefone': telefone, 'CEP': cep, 'Cidade': cidade, 'Estado': estado, 'Situacao': situacaomatricula, 'Email': email},
        ignore_index = True)
        linha = linha + 4
        
    if linha==254: #definir como última linha a parar de ler
        break;
```

The image shows my output in the excel file.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ocrvr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you get rid of the brackets:

```py
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x[0])
```

---

Code for creating the data:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        ['042301IBR', 'D423', 100016571, 'ADAIR FERREIRA DOS SANTOS', pd.Timestamp(1977, 1, 26), 3899919, 3866000, 'Buritis', 'MG'],
        ['042301IBR', 'D423', 100017152, 'ALANA PEREIRA DA CUNHA', pd.Timestamp(1994, 12, 23), 3899929, 3866000, 'Buritis', 'MG'],
        ['042301IBR', 'D423', 100016641, 'ALINE PIRES SILVA', pd.Timestamp(1985, 4, 4), pd.NA, 386600, 'Buritis', 'MG'],
        ['042301IBR', 'D423', 100016882, 'ANA CAROLLVNE RURAES ALVES', pd.Timestamp(1999, 1, 18), 389987, 386600, 'Buritis', 'MG'],
        ['042301IBR', 'D423', 100016494, 'CRISTIANE ROSA DO AMARAL', pd.Timestamp(1988, 11, 7), 3899739, 3866000, 'Buritis', 'MG'],
        ['042301IBR', 'D423', 100016801, 'ELIANE ALVES DA SILVA', pd.Timestamp(1977, 8, 6), '(61)348', 3866000, 'Buritis', 'MG'],
        ['042301IBR', 'D423', 100017010, 'ELIANE LOURENCO VAZ RODRIGUES', pd.Timestamp(1974, 4, 19), 366215, 3866000, 'Buritis', 'MG'],
        ['042301IBR', 'D423', 100016740, 'ELMO LUCIANO RODRIGUES', pd.Timestamp(1990, 8, 8), 389997, 3866000, 'Buritis', 'MG'],
        ['042301IBR', 'D423', 100016926, 'EVA DA COSTA PINHEIRO', pd.Timestamp(1980, 3, 9), 3899930, 3866000, 'Buritis', 'MG'],
        ['042301IBR', 'D423', 100016920, 'JAYNE RODRIGUES DE OLIVEIRA', pd.Timestamp(1999, 3, 23), 389983, 3866000, 'Buritis', 'MG']
    ], 
    columns=['Cod_turma', 'Cod_curso', 'Matricula', 'Nome', 'Data', 'Telefone', 'CEP', 'Cidade', 'Estado'],
).applymap(lambda x: [x])
```

Comment: Problem is: the data is from an excel sheet. It has a lot of lines. How do Io get the data in that format if it's inside a loop?

Comment: @ThiagoRibeiro What do you mean by "if it's inside a loop"? Why do you need a loop? Simply read the data as `df = pd.read_excel('file_name.xlsx')`

Comment: Because the data coming from the excel is messy. Columns aren't in order, so i'm using the dataframe to organize it as well. The loop is in order to get correct data from the generated dataframe, that's why I use iloc (to correctly get the data for each position).

Comment: @ThiagoRibeiro But what about the image that you attached? It does not look messy to me?

Comment: Because that's the output. The input has unorganized data and columns.

Comment: Anyways, i've just testes your applymap code and it works! Thanks a lot, it was really helpful!

Comment: @ThiagoRibeiro But then you already have a way of fixing your messy data. What is it then exactly that you want help with?

Comment: I was asking for help because of the brackets and datetime that was being outputed in a strange format. But I think it's solved now.

Comment: @ThiagoRibeiro Yes, I think removing the brackets also solves the problem with the timestamp. Okey, great. If your problem got solved, please "accept" the answer so that others don't have to spend time looking into the problem.